# Python- Scrape LinkedIn Names

Tags: python, html, selenium

My code will get to the desired webpage by passing in log in and password info.

(You can try any username and password that has an account with LinkedIn in the code below)

I just need to know how to scrape the information, now that I got to the desired page.

If I can start with the names per listing, it would be great.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
productlinks=[]
test1=[]

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fsearch%2Fresults%2Fpeople%2F%3FcurrentCompany%3D%255B%25221252860%2522%255D%26geoUrn%3D%255B%2522103644278%2522%255D%26keywords%3Dsales%26origin%3DFACETED_SEARCH%26page%3D2&fromSignIn=true&trk=cold_join_sign_in"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('Example@gmail.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')

password.send_keys('ExamplePassword')
password.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **scrape html element** using their **Class Name**, with method *find_elements_by_class_name*

See an example below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('User_example')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('Password_example')
password.submit()

time.sleep(1)

MyProfileName=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("profile-rail-card__actor-link")
print("MyProfileName is: " + MyProfileName[0].text.strip())

print("\n List of Names: \n");

#Redirect to another link
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/onboarding/start/people-you-may-know/new/")

time.sleep(2)

Names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("onboarding-card__person-title")
for name in Names:
    print(name.text.strip())
```